# Validate response in my spring project(like Postman test scripts)

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, postman

Now I'm developing with spring, intellij.

I want to validate the api response body at my `spring project` as we do in `postman` 'Test' function.
I've done like below in `postman`

```
pm.test("some api test", function() {    
    pm.expect(pm.response.json()).eql(JSON.parse('{"success": true,"result": {"a": "value", "b": "value"}}'))
})
```

Postman is very good. But I want to put the above codes in my project and manage them with git.
I can't use`mockMvc` because I won't validate localhost:8080's data.
I have to validate with real server data. Because all dev data is not enough to validate.

Is there any good library?
If I can manage test code in my project, it is also enough(Don't need to be JVM language).
I tried restClient in intellij, but I don't know how to validate response body on this library like Postman.

Comment: try rest-assured written in java + groovy, it support spring.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 It's possible to do what I wanted with RestAssured. Thanks!